# How can I install nagios-plugins-extra on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, ubuntu-18.04

I have servers running on Ubuntu 14.10 and have started upgrading them to 18.04. However, my installation playbooks (Ansible) are failing on the apt install of `nagios-plugins-extra`.

I looked for this package and it looks like it's only available for Trusty and Xenial, not for Bionic.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=nagios-plugins-extra&searchon=names

The description for Xenial says 'transactional dummy package', does this mean it's now part of the regular `nagios-plugins`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the `nagios-plugins-<whatever>` packages have been renamed to `monitoring-plugins-<whatever>`.

See the [Ubuntu package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=monitoring-plugins).

There is no `monitoring-plugins-extra`, because the contents of that package were merged into `monitoring-plugins-standard`.

(The only plugins that were in `nagios-plugins-extra`, [as of 14.04 anyway](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/nagios-plugins-extra/filelist), were `check_fping` and `check_game`.)